# Bitcoin-cli how to get balance of a wallet on different node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, balance, daemon, cli

I am making a bitcoin mobile application, and I an trying to get the balance of a wallet that is on the mobile phone, from a daemon that is running on a separate node. The mobile wallet is connected to this node and can use any of the CLI commands such as `getinfo` `getbalance` etc.

What CLI commands do I pass to the daemon to give me the balance of the wallet on my mobile application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot because Bitcoin Core does not store such information. Bitcoin Core does not store all information for all addresses, it only stores information for its own addresses and the lower level information needed for verifying transactions (addresses are a higher level abstraction). There are no commands that allow you to get the balances or transactions for a given address not in the Bitcoin Core wallet because such information is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a database dump from blockchair.com at https://gz.blockchair.com/bitcoin/addresses/
The database is updated daily and is contains a balance of satoshis for every address on the network.